# Navigation CSS not responding on IE/chrome

Tags: php, css, html, doctype

Been working on my website and its live now. But with latest IE, chrome, and some Firefox, my Image sizing in my navigation is not responding. On iOS it works great, and same with android default Internet browsers.

Other questions I've researched said to declare doctype in all files which I have already.

How do I fix this problem?

(All testing through a cross browser tester)

Safari on OS Yosemite **Correct**
[image]

IE 11
[image]

Firefox 40
[image]

Chrome 45/ Opera 31
[image]

NAV PHP (Included in index.html):

```
<nav>
<div>
    <a href="/">
        <div id="logo"><img src="/Images/7serviceLOGOblue2.png" alt="Home"/></div>
        <div id="headtag"><img src="/Images/title.png" alt="Home"/></div>
        <div id="tagline"><img src="/Images/tag_line.png" alt="Home"/></div>
    </a>
</div>
<div> 
    <a href="/" class="here">Home</a>
    <a href="/about.php">About</a>      
    <a href="/services.php">Services</a>
    <a href="/pricing.php">Pricing</a>
    <a href="/contact.php">Contact</a>
    <!--input id="srchbar" type="search" placeholder="Search"-->
</div>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle to Header/Header CSS with stock images.
https://jsfiddle.net/blackRob4953/238n7ddk/

Comment: By "not responding" you mean it does not work? Or does it cause the browser to hang? Please provide examples / screenshots of how it's not working and what behavior you expect. And add the relevant CSS/HTML, please.

Comment: Replying from mobile. Will update with screenshots in 20 mins. If you have any of those browsers. Link is www.se7enservice.com

Comment: @LarsGendner Added the screenshots and coding for you

Comment: `<a>` is an inline-level element but `<div>` is a block-level element. Inline elements cannot contain block-level elements. (i.e. `<div>` cannot be a child of `<a>`).

Comment: @Dai Ok, how do I fix that, can they all still be a clickable link? do they have to be separate links each? How do I go about it?

Comment: please change title to: "
Navigation links not working on IE/chrome
"

Comment: @11111000000 The LINKS do work, its the image links that just won't size properly in certain browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>

    <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/Images/7serviceLOGOblue2.png" alt="Home"/></a></div>
    <div id="headtag"><a href="/"><img src="/Images/title.png" alt="Home"/></a></div>
    <div id="tagline"><a href="/"><img src="/Images/tag_line.png" alt="Home"/></a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, and the images just return to default sizing and don't resize when I change the height and widths...

Comment: you need to change css then

Comment: you were right. This works, I replaced my code with what you wrote above. Then just have to redirect the CSS ID tags to #logo img{}, #headtag img{}, and #tagline img{}. and resize the images. but now works across all browsers . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use `<img>` tags inside the `<a>`, without `<div>`s:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de">
    <img id="logo" src="http://www.lehigh.edu/google/google_search.png" alt="Home"/>
    <img id="headtag" src="http://codeboxr.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/6_logo_predesign.jpg" alt="Home"/>
    <img id="tagline" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-2-4845213826678784.3-hp.gif" alt="Home"/>
</a>
```

Comment: When I execute this, the image display in a column, and not inline as they do now on the site. I tried using flex direction:row and displaying:inline, but it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Trying giving your images a max-width of 100% via CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Tried, and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

a. Can we see your `CSS3` code? Because it is unclear what "Navigation not responding in CSS" means. Navigation triggers, save :hover, etc are not CSS functions.

b. Most folk are using Edge not IE, if the browser and hardware are modern. In fact, the last 3 years have seen no one use Explorer browser, nor request compatibility development for IE.

c. If using a hybrid jquery and css, you may find conflicts depending on the function. Example: iOS uses `touchstart` instead of `.on(click)`, etc. Defining the function for the appropriate browser would make better sense for responsiveness.

d. Image sizing and display is dependent on the container the `img` is in and whether or not it is `static` meaning `img src=""` w/ or w/out hyperlink or used as a `background` property. If the later, you need to add the `background-size` to the CSS3.

```
#elem { background:url:({myimg location}) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;}
```

OR

```
#elem {background:url({my img location}) center no-repeat; float:left; max-width:50%;}
```

Comment: A. That is my Stylesheet for my Navigation, So I'm not sure what else you would like, unless you want the full site nav. Is that what you want to see? B. If that's the case, then just need help for chrome/firefox users. I run Mac so not really sure what others mainly use. C. None of those, just basic html5 tags D.  Please explain the container more? The Div is my container, when I remove the div, the images won't size per my coding

Comment: Simple. Put the image(s) into a div(s) as backgrounds and size accordingly. You can then decide how-to link them (navigation) either as  hyperlink-direct or a jquery on.(something) function.